# Gradle: How to copy all dependencies jar files from a specified configuration without inherited

Tags: java, gradle

I need to copy all `compileTest` 3rd party dependencies jars from all projects to a separate directory. But I need **only direct dependencies**, not inherited from a super configurations, i.e. I don't need dependendencies from `compile` configuration.

"Default" approach like the following doesn't work for me.

```
task copyTestLibs(type: Copy) {
    into('libs-test')
    def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll { it.plugins.hasPlugin('java') }
    from javaProjects*.configurations.testCompile
}
```

So is there any way to copy configuration's direct dependencies without inherited ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally I found a solution:

```
task copyTestLibs(type: Copy) {
    into('libs-test')
    def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll { it.plugins.hasPlugin('java') }
    from javaProjects.collect {
        it.configurations.testCompile.copy().files {!(it instanceof ProjectDependency)}}.flatten().unique()
}
```

Comment: just a note about this snippet: it will resolve the dependencies at configuration time. so even when the task is not triggered the dependencies are resolved from repositories

Answer (score -1):

The `copy()` method of Configuration provides a way to create another configuration with all direct dependencies and no transitive dependencies in it. Have a look at the gradle dsl  reference [http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:copy()](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration%3acopy%28%29)

for details. A solution using the copy() method can look like this:

```
task copyTestLibs(type: Copy) {
    into('libs-test')
    def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll { it.plugins.hasPlugin('java') }
    from javaProjects*.configurations.testCompile*.copy()
}
```

Comment: Yep, it's a right direction, but your example fails with an error: `No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.copy() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: I had a typo in the snippet. I've changed ´javaProjects*.configurations.testCompile.copy()´to javaProjects*.configurations.testCompile*.copy() now it should work

Comment: You should add an explanation to this answer if possible